# Movable popup div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a task of making a color picker inside a movable popup div. does anybody have a good site which has a good tutorial on it?

Comment: [Here's a tutorial for a movable div](http://waseemblog.com/42/movable-div-using-javascript.html) and [here's a library for a color picker.](http://waseemblog.com/42/movable-div-using-javascript.html)

Comment: Use Jquery Dialog is draggable http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ draggable http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/